# How to use JDK 12 with Android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-12

I am running Android Studio 3.5 Beta 5. I have been following a rabbit hole starting with trying to run unit tests with Robolectric against Android SDK 29. I saw an error that required running with Java 9. When I went to install JDK 9, it directed me to 10, then 11, then 12!

I downloaded JDK 12 and now I would like to configure Android Studio's JDK location to be 12. However, when I attempt to do that, I get the following warning message: "Please choose a valid JDK 8 directory". See screenshots below.

Is there another setting I have to change to get this dialog to allow me to choose a JDK greater than 8? Or is it just not possible?

[image: project structure dialog]

[image: warning message]

Comment: It's not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you actually can compile Android apps using a higher JDK version while targeting Java 8 within your apps. it seems that this was supported in Android Studio versions before 3.5 beta 3, and according to the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134033994), they plan on fixing this.

in the meanwhile, you can compile with higher JDK versions on the command line with Gradle without any issues.

Comment: Yes @ahmedre is right. His answer should be the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle Java and Android Java aren't the same - they don't even use the same virtual machine.

So Sadly u can not use it now, until Android support it.